# How create nested permailnks wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have a plugin activation hook. When trying to create a page with the link "/test/test"
Creates a "test-test" link.
How to make the correct link?
For creating posts I use the `wp_insert_post()` function

Comment: When you create the page and save it, WP converts its name to slug. While doing it WP replaces spaces and slashes with dash. To achive that you need first to create a parent page (it can be named as test) and then when you create new page you have to select parent ("test"), then permalink will contain slash

Comment: Can’t I do without a parent page?

Comment: Even if you set in Permalinks settings in WP smth like `/%postname%/%postname%/`, it will revert URL to single `/%postname%/`

Comment: You can create catregory test and put pages to this category

Comment: Slash is used by routing engine, so I thinkit's impossible to use slash in the name